# Best way to validate json file in java

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I want to validate the JSON file. I checked readValue from fasterXML but I see it return object. Is there any to validate JSON files efficiently without compromising performance?

```
public <T> T readValue(File src, Class<T> valueType)
```

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with it returning an object? And what makes you think this has a performance problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong to return an object. The question is about performance and a better approach for validating JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a JSON Schema for validating the content of the file. [networknt/json-schema](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator) is Java based and supports Jackson.